# Wordpress: Removing DIV Classes / Visibly & in code from certain pages

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress

Wordpress: Removing DIV Classes / Visibly & in code from certain pages

I am trying to limit the number of outbound links in the HTML source code on certain pages. I know I can visibly hide various elements like this:

```
.postid-30134 .twp-ticket-pin.slick-slide  {
  display: none;
}
```

But all the hidden parts are still in the source code - including say for instance theme elements with loads of outbound links.

How do I "clean the code" - and basically "remove" the div tags instead of hiding them?

Comment: I tried adding:
-
 if ( $(element).css('display') == 'none' ){
    $(element).remove();
}

To the end of main.js ... to no avail

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove specific `divs` from source code, get all the `div's` which has class `twp-ticket` and `pin.slick-slide` nested inside `postid-30134`, loop over it and remove the div.

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.postid-30134 .twp-ticket-pin.slick-slide')
  .forEach(div => div.remove());
```

```html
<div class="postid-30134">
  <div class="twp-ticket-pin slick-slide">Div One</div>
  <div class="twp-ticket-pin slick-slide">Div Two</div>
  <div>Do not remove</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for looking at it.

document.querySelectorAll('.postid-30134 .twp-ticket-pin.slick-slide') .forEach(div => div.remove());

Where exactly do I insert the above? I tried randomly dumping it to the themes .js file. And do I simply reproduce it endlessly for all posts / div classes or can I "bulk" do it in one command?

Comment: In the `javascript` file that is associated with the `html` i:e `<div class="postid-30134">...</div>`